# How to stop Windows server from locking a file?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server, file-locking

I have to work with a buggy accounting application that locks the data file and doesnt release the lock when it stops using it. So next person trying to access the file gets Access Denied.

This can be temporarily fixed by deleting the filelock handle with Unlocker, but it has to be done every time, and is very annoying.

Is there a way to configure (Windows 2003 server) to disable file locks on ONE particular file? I found some info on how to disable file locks system-wide but I dont want to do this for the whole server, just ONE file.

Comment: Or perhaps a script that deletes all file locks from a file, say, every 5 minutes? Could that be done?

Comment: @AndreiKravcheni yes it does!

Comment: Deleting the file every five minutes as a script could be dangerous and corrupt good data. Not a high risk, but a risk.

Comment: I dont want to delete the file, just the locking handles that are locking the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Unlocker provides a command-line interface to run it. So I created a batch file that runs unlocker and unlocks this file on demand. Not ideal but its less annoying than other options:

unlocker "C:\Path\File.lck" /S /D